# Append JSON to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have a JSON file with 3 objects that I need to parse into certain elements on a widget, but I am not sure what's the best method to do that.

Could somebody help me find a method?

HTML:

```
<div class="widget style1" style="background-color: #F59C1A!important; color: #FFF">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 text-left">
        <span>Course Weeks</span>
        <h2 class="font-bold" id="DailyChange"></h2>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top: 15px">
            This Year Change: <strong id="ThisYearChange"></strong>
        </div>
        <div>
            Future Years Change: <strong id="FutureYearsChange"></strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <span class="label label-danger pull-right">Daily Change</span>
        <i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-5x pull-right" style="padding-top: 20px;opacity: 0.4"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

 var url = "/Main/CourseWeeksDCRead";

 var mftr1 = String($('#MainSchoolGeography').select2("val"));
 var mftr2 = String($('#MainCentre').select2("val"));
 var mftr3 = String($('#MainSalesRegion').select2("val"));
 var mftr4 = String($('#MainSalesPerson').select2("val"));
 var mftr5 = String($('#MainAgentCountry').select2("val"));
 var mftr6 = String($('#MainAgentGroup').select2("val"));
 var mftr7 = String($('#MainAdmissionsRegion').select2("val"));
 var mftr8 = String($('#MainProductCategory').select2("val"));

 var Object = { "agentCountry": mftr1, "centre": mftr2, "salesRegion": mftr3, "salesPerson": mftr4, "agentCountry": mftr5, "agentGroup": mftr6, "admissionsRegion": mftr7, "productCategory": mftr8 };

    $.post(url, Object, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

JSON:

```
[{"DailyChange":1124.60},{"ThisYearChange":435.60},{"FutureYearsChange":680.00}]
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult CourseWeeksDCRead(string schoolCountry, string Centre, string salesRegion, string salesPerson, string agentCountry, string agentGroup, string admissionsRegion, string productCategory)
    {
        Services.sqlService ss = new Services.sqlService();

        return Json(ss.GetCourseWeeksDCList(schoolCountry, Centre, salesRegion, salesPerson, agentCountry, agentGroup, admissionsRegion, productCategory), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

DAL:

```
public DataTable GetCourseWeeksDC(string schoolCountry, string Centre, string salesRegion, string salesPerson, string agentCountry, string agentGroup, string admissionsRegion, string productCategory)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr1);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DashBoards_DailyChange", sqlConnection);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (schoolCountry == "null")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolcountry", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolcountry", schoolCountry);
        }

        if (Centre == "null")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@centre", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@centre", Centre);
        }

        if (salesRegion == "null")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salesRegion", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salesRegion", salesRegion);
        }

        if (agentCountry == "null")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agentcountry", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agentcountry", agentCountry);
        }

        if (agentGroup == "null")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agentgroup", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agentgroup", agentGroup);
        }

        if (admissionsRegion == "null")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admissionregion", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admissionregion", admissionsRegion);
        }

        if (productCategory == "null")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productcategory", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productcategory", productCategory);
        }

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Measure", "Weeks Course");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(dr);
        sqlConnection.Close();

        return dt;
    }
```

SERVICE:

```
public List<CourseWeeksDC> GetCourseWeeksDCList(string schoolCountry, string Centre, string salesRegion, string salesPerson, string agentCountry, string agentGroup, string admissionsRegion, string productCategory)
    {

        List<CourseWeeksDC> courseweeks = new List<CourseWeeksDC>();
        sqlDal dal = new sqlDal();

        foreach (DataRow item in dal.GetCourseWeeksDC(schoolCountry, Centre, salesRegion, salesPerson, agentCountry, agentGroup, admissionsRegion, productCategory).Rows)
        {
            CourseWeeksDC courseweek = new CourseWeeksDC();
            courseweek.DailyChange = (decimal)item["DailyChange"];
            courseweek.ThisYearChange = (decimal)item["ThisYearChange"];
            courseweek.FutureYearsChange = (decimal)item["FutureYearsChange"];

            courseweeks.Add(courseweek);
        }
        return courseweeks;
    }
```

Comment: What good approach did you try?

Comment: `var data = [{"DailyChange":1124.60},{"ThisYearChange":435.60},{"FutureYearsChange":680.00}]
alert(data[0].DailyChange);
alert(data[1].ThisYearChange);
alert(data[2].FutureYearsChange);`

Comment: How are you reading/parsing the Json?

Comment: via the url...something like this: var url = "/Main/CourseWeeksDCRead";

Comment: Might be best to show what Js you have already.

Comment: i have updated with all the code...the current post method returns the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you double check the Json returned. It looks like the service is returning a list of objects, each with the 3 properties. so the Json would have 1 object in the array with 3 properties.

```
[{"DailyChange":1124.60, "ThisYearChange":435.60, "FutureYearsChange":680.00}]
```

So all 3 properties can be found at index 0.

```
var daily = json[0].DailyChange;
var year = json[0].ThisYearChange;
var future = json[0].FutureYearsChange;
```

Comment: retured all properties index 0

Comment: yes, thank you. managed to get it to work with all the indexes being 0 :)

Comment: I would appreciate if you marked the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$('#ThisYearChange').html(json[1].ThisYearChange);
```

Comment: i have tried something like this but i get an uncaught typeerror: cannot read property, $.post(url, Object, function (data) {
                $('#ThisYearChange').html(json[1].ThisYearChange);
            });

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON.parse() method which parses json in to the objet then easily data can be shown. Below is a sample code :

```
function AppendValues(jsonstring // this will be having json string)
{
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(jsonstring );
$("#ThisYearChange").val(parsedObject.ThisYearChange);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
function ParseJson(jsonValue)
{
    var parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonValue);   
    $('#DailyChange').text(parsedJson[0].DailyChange);
    $('#ThisYearChange').text(parsedJson[1].ThisYearChange);
    $('#FutureYearsChange').text(parsedJson[2].FutureYearsChange);
}
```

Comment: tried this but doesnt work..not sure why no errors in log

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

$.each(data, function(i,v){
    $.each(v,function(k,z){
        $('#'+k).html(z);
    });
});
```